# Endnote: citing highlighted text from a PDF as direct quote

Tags: citations

In Endnote X8 for Windows, how can I use the text I've highlighted in a PDF (stored directly in the Endnote library) as a direct quote in my Word document, and cite it properly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to a specific software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked a follow-up question later ([here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94844/endnote-inserting-page-number-at-the-end-of-the-citation)) but this contains a specific aspect - pulling a highlighted citation directly from the PDF for an in-text quote. There is not a way to automatically pull highlighted text from a PDF so I would recommend the following:

1. Open the PDF and find the quote and page number. Type the quote carefully so that it is accurately represented.
2. Insert the citation as normal following the quote.

For an APA example you might have:

> "This is an important quote which justifies my research" (Jackson, 2017, p. 1)

or with the field codes visible the citation would be `{jackson, 2017@1}`.