# Endnote: inserting page number at the end of the citation

Tags: citations

What is the proper way to insert an in-text citation using Endnote X8, where you first cite the author, year, following with the quote, and *then* with the page number in a source? (see an image attached for the example of the formatting). [citation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrIm6.png)

Comment: Can't you add the page number by hand as normal text? Then, the [Author (Year)] part is a normal reference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to a specific software

Comment: @Mark I sure can. I was hoping there is a way to do that in such a way, that these two references count as one, rather than two separate references of the same source (I. e., author, year, and page number).

Comment: @AntonK I would not add the page number as reference. Besides that, mentioning the same reference multiple times doesn't count as multiple references, as far as I would say. Where do you _count_?

Comment: @Mark If I insert author and year first using Endnote, write direct quote, and then put a page number (also using Endnote), this counts as two separate references (in the Endnote Word Add-in). I wanted to automate the process with Endnote and make it count as one reference

Comment: @Mark if you check the screenshot in the question body, you will see what I mean. I'm putting a page number after a direct quote to indicate the end of the quote better.

Comment: I haven't used Endnote for a while (for many reasons), but I would do the following: `{Author (Year)} "quote" (page xxx)` with the part in {} being Endnote reference. The quote text and page numbers I would add as normal text.

Comment: @Mark thanks! That's most likely the way to go. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked a slightly different question earlier ([here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94841/endnote-citing-highlighted-text-from-a-pdf-as-direct-quote/94868#94868)) but this one differentiates your goal to separate the citation and page number.

I prefer to do as @Mark mentions in the comments, I add an endnote formatted citation for the author and year, then manually type in the page number. You can type field codes for the citation to list the author in-text by putting `{jackson, 2017@@author-year}`. Depending on the reference style you are using it might be appropriate to put the author, year, and page number before the quote, which you can do with the field code `{jackson, 2017 @1@author-year}`. Lastly, you can put a citation with just a page number by excluding the author and year from the reference (right-click or go to the "Edit & Manage Citation(s)" menu) yet entering the page number in the citation. If you know the record number the field code will simply be `{#616@3}`.

Here's a summary:

`{Jackson, 2017 #615@1}` turns to

> (Jackson, 2017, p. 1)

`{Jackson, 2017 #615@1@author-year}` turns to

> Jackson (2017, p. 1)

`{Jackson, 2017 #615} said “quotations are important” {,  #615@1}` turns to

> Jackson (2017) said “quotations are important” (p. 1).

Whether you insert the citation multiple times from Endnote, as long as you are referencing the same record you'll only see 1 reference in the document or in the manage citations menu. For example, I have a document with the all three combinations and it has 4 citations but only 1 reference.

The main reason why I manually enter the page numbers is the difference in citation formatting for page numbers. If I end up submitting to a different venue, thus changing the citation style in Endnote, I've had page numbers disappear. So I prefer to have a little more manual control over that aspect.

[image]